# Export multiple AOL emails at once?

Tags: email, aol

Helping my dad for legal purposes needs to export a bunch of emails to provide to discovery.

There are hundreds.  They are in his AOL account.  My brother already put all the emails he needs into folders.

How can I export all these emails into files, either pdf or something?

Comment: Please do some research before asking, see: https://www.google.com/search?q=export+aol+emails+to+pdf

Comment: The only methods I saw were printing to PDF one at a time.  This has hundreds, maybe thousands of emails.  That is the issue I am trying to resolve.

Comment: Just clicking the first link in my given search goes to https://www.arysontechnologies.com/how-to/save-aol-email-as-pdf-documents/, which has a "Method2"  [Automatic Process to Save Your AOL Email to PDF Documents](https://www.arysontechnologies.com/how-to/save-aol-email-as-pdf-documents/#:~:text=Method%202%3A-,Automatic%20Process%20to%20Save%20Your%20AOL%20Email%20to%20PDF%20Documents,-Another%20method%20to)   (But there will be other possibilities too)

Comment: IT is unfortunately denying the download in method 2, says it has a trojan.  I can't verify that.  But seems not an option.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're doing it in the office instead of at home? If it's work-related and needed for legal purposes I'd talk to my manager so he can get the IT guys to come up with a better solution.

Comment: In what format do you need the emails? If you have an email client such as Outlook, you could move all the emails from an AOL mailbox to an Outlook data file(`.pst`) - [link](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/export-aol-emails-to-pst/).

Comment: Or take them all locally with Thunderbird, too.